# Can particle with fractional charge exist in isolation?

Tags: particle-physics, charge, quarks, discrete, confinement

Since quarks are ruled out I wonder if it is possible for free fractional charge to exist not counting virtual particles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the data gathered over the last 200 years or so show only integer multiples of charges, and the models that classify the behavior of particles are successful in predicting new data. Fractional charges arouse in the models to describe the symmetries of hadrons which were experimentally found to be composite.

The models have not been invalidated, within the mainstream  there are no free fractional charges. They have not been observed and that (non observation) is what the models describe.

Comment: This is not my field, but I would suspect that we have no reason to rule out the possibility (c.f. magnetic monopoles).  Is that correct?

Comment: The only reason comes of the good fit of the standard model to innumerable data , and the model does not allow free fractional charges. If experimentally one is found, it would need a reworking of the standard model. I think the magnetic  monopole  does not have electric charge, but it is easier to accomodate it in extensions of the standard model  .

Comment: There's no reason to include it in a *model* since there is no evidence.  But it can't be ruled out as a possibility.  The original question is "is it possible".  Yes, it's possible.  But until we have reason to consider it, we won't.

Answer (score -2):

Good question. Not very desirable from the point of view of supporters of the quark model which is a part of the standard model, but still.

I'm afraid, that no fractional charges is possible in Nature. Not in isolation, not with confinment.

The root of mistake with fractional charges is belief (not proven) of physical community that proton and neutron are similar particles which are distinguished by quantum number isospin.

If you thust that proton and neutron is similar particles you have to trust in fractional charges.

But, if you would analize what is neutron, you would quickly go to conclusion, that neutron have to be a composite of proton and negative pion. As well as atomic nuclei.

In than case you would quickly go to conclustion,  than fractictional charges are not needed.

I wonder how many centuries will it take from physical community to understand what SU(3) symmetry really shows, apart from mistake with wrong identification of neutron as elementary particle like proton, made in wild 1934 year :)

Comment: Are you claiming that the neutron is a bound state of a proton and  a $\pi^-$, and that protons are elementary?

Comment: Not bound state, but composite (compound).

Comment: Yes, it looks like negative pion is elementary, proton is elementary and both consitute neutron and nuclei. In that case beta-decay is much simpler that the Standard model states and is just known reaction of conversion of charged meson (negative pion) to charged lepton (electron) and emission of antineutrino. Proton does not participate in beta decay in that case. That is the Rutherford-Kudan, or the proton-negative pion model of neutron and atomic nuclei

Comment: Neutron is not baryon in that case. But similar to atomic nuclei composite (compound).

Comment: That suggest that Sir Rutherford were right when he stated that nuclei consists of positive proton and negative particle. The only error of Sir Rutherford in that case was that he stated that negative particle is electron (with no evidence of it, but with limited knowledge of charged particles). That is why the model has name Rutherford-Kudan. Where proton as component of nuclei was identified by Sir Ernest Rutherford in 1919 and negative pion was identified as another component of nucleus by Pavel Kudan in 2019.

Comment: Isospin is fake, if so. And 'isospin conservation'  is just conservation of mesonic number of nuclei. Beta-decay change number of mesons.

Comment: And, dear anna_v, during development of model I found the answer on your old question what is origin of strong interaction between proton and negative pion in that case - the nuclear binding energy. It is correct, that it cannot be electrodinamic force, too big, you were right. That is even more interesting and exciting.